# SSL Configuration Problem

Tags: https, security-certificate, godaddy, java

I've generated an SSL certificate with keytool:

```
keytool -keystore keystore -alias mySite -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
```

I got this configured and working fine, but obviously it wasn't signed by a trusted CA, so I generated a CSR:

```
keytool -certreq -alias mySite -keystore keystore -file mySite.csr
```

GoDaddy gave me two certificates back, which I imported into my keystore:

```
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias mySite.com -file mySite.com.crt
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias gd_bundle -file gd_bundle.crt
```

I thought this would be sufficient, but I am still getting an untrusted certificate warning when I hit my app through the browser. Am I missing a step? My app is running on Jetty, and the only configuration I've provided is the keystore and the key-password.

I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for a couple hours, I was able to find a solution.  I ended up using `openssl` instead of `keytool`:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out mysite.key 2048
openssl req -new -key mysite.key -out mysite.csr
```

Submit the CSR, and once you get issued a cert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile gd_bundle.crt -in mysite.com.crt -inkey mysite.key -out mysite.pkcs12
java -classpath jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:jetty-6.1.26.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.PKCS12Import mysite.pkcs12 keystore
```

Hope others find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following what all was done differently.  Was the key difference that you used openssl instead of keytool to request the certificate?  What was used to do the import?  The commands listed in your answer:

openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile gd_bundle.crt -in mysite.com.crt -inkey mysite.key -out mysite.pkcs12
java -classpath jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:jetty-6.1.26.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.PKCS12Import mysite.pkcs12 keystore

These only show the "openssl pkcs12 -export" and a "java -classpath" command.  Did you still use keytool for the -import?